# TeamCity reports failed MbUnit tests twice

Tags: teamcity, mbunit, gallio

I am using the Gallio MSBuildTasks library to run MbUnit tests inside JetBrains TeamCity. When tests pass they report as having passed once, however when they fail they appear as having failed twice. Once with the Namespace and once without. This looks something like:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/191/capturegv.png/

There are two tests here (Test and Test2) and they both fail. However TeamCity reckons they have each failed twice, displaying each one with a namespace (UnitTests) and then without. This is not just the report in the TeamCity website interface, I have pre-test commit enabled and they show up as failing twice in there too.

Has anyone else experienced this and if so how have you solved it?